# Какая максимальная длина строки для пути в Qt5

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, qt5

Обратил внимание что изменение расположения исходников влияет на ошибку undefined reference to, таким образом предположил, что проблема в длине пути (на английском). Хотел поинтересоваться какую максимальную длину пути можно использовать в приложениях Qt5? 
Ubuntu 16.04 x64, qt 5.1, qtcreator 3.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ошибка вида "undefined reference to" - это обычно ошибка линковки. Она возникает, если линковищик не может найти скомпилированные .a файлы. Если в qmake/make скрипте прописаны абсолютные пути, то это и есть причиной.

Я думаю, что длина строки для пути не должна влиять на на Ваш случай. На всякий случай, она обычно ограничена где то в 4096 байт. [Здесь](https://serverfault.com/questions/9546/filename-length-limits-on-linux) есть детальное описание.

P.S. по моим наблюдениям, если общая длина пути + имя не превышает 255, то на большинстве систем нет никаких проблем с длиной пути.

P.S.S. Это не зависит от версии QtCreator:)

Comment: При правильном написании кода, а именно с использованием функций _*at()_ длина пути ограничивается лишь ресурсами памяти. И да, Qt тут вообще не причём.

Comment: каких функций? и да, длина ограничевается ресурсами. Это очень по К.О.:)

Comment: *openat()* и т.п. Неочевидно, если есть заданные стандартами или в процессе работы ограничениями.